# PHP form reloads current page on POST action, rather than displaying 'success.php' page. Why?

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a PHP form that submits some data to a database. The form action code is as follows:

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>"
      method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
```

The $editFormAction references the following block of code:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO gifts (giftid, customerid, itemtype, itemtitle,                                                                                            itemdescription, itemurl, dateadded, received, datereceived, vendor, ordernumber) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['giftid'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['customerid'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['itemtype'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['itemtitle'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['itemdescription'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['itemurl'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['dateadded'], "date"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['received'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['datereceived'], "date"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['vendor'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['ordernumber'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_testing_registryconnection, $testing_registryconnection);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $testing_registryconnection) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "success.php";
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

I've used a variation of this code in many other pages, but for this specific project, while the form data is indeed inserted to the MySQL database, the form page simply reloads to display a blank form. And if I remember correctly, this exact code worked as it was supposed to for a while on this project, but something must have changed that is interfering with the redirect to 'success.php'.

Any tips for what I should be checking? Do you need to see more code?

Comment: So... you're submitting the form to itself, and then redirecting to a success page?  Why not just submit to the success page?  My thought would be, are relative addresses allowed in the header Location?  Just a first thought without looking at it too closely.

Comment: And if you must redirect, what's the point of the `sprintf` at the end?  Couldn't you just have `header("Location: $insertGoTo");` and save a step?

Comment: Definitely worth as an answer on both points @Mike

Comment: As Mike mentioned, maybe you could do `header("Location: %s", $insertGoTo);` instead of `header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));` -  or `header("Location: $insertGoTo");` instead of `header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));`

Comment: Are you getting a MySQL error? Are you outputting to browser before `header()` call?

Comment: @MikeBrant Do you think that the double-quotes around the `.php` file might be treated as a string `$insertGoTo = "success.php";` ?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if `mysql_` hasn't been replaced by `mysqli` on your server (unless you're running your own webserver). Many web hosts have since gotten rid of `mysql_` altogether and is already deprecated.

Comment: @Fred No that is not a problem.  The main issue here is that you really haven't talked about what debugging efforts you have made that might help lead to the identification of the problem. The code in and of itself doesn't look problematic. But not sure if there is code before this that could be creating output, or whether you are getting mysql error causing script to die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine my two comments above... what I would try first is to replace `$insertGoTo` with an absolute value (ie http://www.mydomain.com/success.php) and then replace the last line (for the sake of cleaning it up) with: `header("Location: $insertGoTo");`.  See if that works?

Comment: I'm starting to get second thoughts Mike. After analyzing the OP's `$insertGoTo` and others under it, notice that the header might be redirecting to a query string added on to the location.

Comment: Sorry for my late response...thought I had subscribed to the question and hadn't gotten any notifications of responses...the code was generated using Dreamweaver, so other than editing a few variables, I'm not sure why it was generated the way it was. I'll try a few of your suggestions and report back.

Comment: OK, I tried `header("Location: $insertGoTo");` and changing the `$insertGoTo` code to the following `$insertGoTo = "http://localhost/registrycode/admin/success.php";` and the form is still behaving the same way. Prior to all of this, the form was correctly redirecting to the success.php page as I intended.  Not sure exactly what changed...this is both on my test machine and on the live server.

Comment: Also tried `header("Location: %s", $insertGoTo);`  same behavior.

Comment: To answer the earlier question, I'm not getting any MySQL or other errors...upon clicking the "submit" button, the form values get written successfully to the database (I immediately verify that), and the form page reloads with empty form fields.